# Specifying a `const int&` that doesn't bind temporaries

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

Is there a way to specify a constant reference as an argument type (of a function) that doesn't bind temporaries?
That is, is there a standard way to specify both that the reference is `const` but that it can only bind to non-temporary values, with attempting to bind to a temporary resulting in a compiler error¹?

---

For example, in the case of the constructor of a class `X`,

```
class X
{
public:
    X(const int &value)
      : mValue(value)
    {}

private:
    const int &mValue;
};
```

what would be a nice way to ensure that

```
class Y
{
public:

    /* ... */

    X* GetXForValue() const
    {
        return new X(mValue);
    }

private:
    int mValue;
};
```

compiles, but when called with a temporary, e.g. `X x(100);`, it does not?

---

¹) I could overload the function for `int&&` and then not define it, but that would give the wrong idea and only result in a linker error.

Comment: you could `X(const int&& value) = delete;` instead of not defining the function causing a linker error

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I thought that only the default constructor could be marked as deleted?

Comment: @MicroVirus *Any* function can be marked as deleted.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Right, TIL. That does make the overload solution viable.

Comment: most likely, you want the constructor to be explicit as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A general solution is to add a deleted overload:

```
void foo(const int&);

void foo(const int&&) = delete;
```

The latter is a better match for rvalues, and thus the undesired program would select the deleted overload and become ill-formed.

Comment: Does it have to be `const` in `const int&&`? It is unnecessary, right?

Comment: @Rakete1111: Ugh. It depends. For built-in types, if you *only* want to disallow prvalues, then you don't need a qualification, because built-in prvalues are never qualified. But user-defined types may be qualified, and also the OP asked for rvalues, not prvalues, and xvalues can certainly be qualified.

Comment: Builtin *xvalues* can be qualified, so the const is significant even for `int` if you want to disallow rvalues.

Comment: I didn't realise that any function could be deleted, as I'd only ever heard it for the special member functions; this will work nicely then. Thanks.

Comment: @MicroVirus: You can extend the idea to disallow conversions in a more general way: `template <typename T> foo(T &&) = delete;`, and now add non-template overloads for the allowed signatures. (E.g. preventing inadvertent integer promotions or arithmetic conversions.)